# ExtJS combobox is not selectable in IE7

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, internet-explorer-7

Hi I have very simple dropdown in ExtJs it works fine in ie8 and above but in ie7 it not possible to select a value from the list.

It looks like in the picture bellow, when I press on testAccount nothing happening.

[image]

Here is the code

```
 Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
                renderTo: 'ddlAccount',
                value: '',
                disabled: false,
                id: 'cboAccount',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',
                width: 219,
                height: 22,
                store: accounts,
                queryMode: 'local',
                editable: false,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                typeAhead: false,
                allowBlank: false,
                hideLabel: true,
                tabIndex: 2
            });
```

Comment: is it specific to ie 7 only ? if so does your extjs version supports ie 7 ?

Comment: Yes it IE 7 only and ExtJs supports it

Comment: It might be a `z-index` issue. IE7 has a habit of layering things strangely, and I've had cases where an item was visible but unclickable because another transparent element was being layered on top of it. It's really hard to test these things without Dev Tools; IE7 doesn't have the F12 Devtools feature, but if you can make IE8 or later do the same thing in IE7-compatibility mode you might be able to use the dev tools there.

Comment: assigning default css properties again might fix this issue. like for `div` element giving `display: block`. and also sometimes using `float` css property also works. I am just sharing my exp. I hope it will do the trick for you.